# How can I customize the user-access to Mailing lists?

Tags: civimail, permissions, mailing, accessibility

Its not clear to me how I as an admin can control the access for different groups to their mailing lists.
For example, the leader of group A should be restricted to mail to group A.

Is it possible to create some kind of mail-distributor (a mailing-adress to which I can send a mail and from which it is distributed to a mailing list).

kind regards

Answer (score 1):

You want to set [ACLs](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/#native-civicrm-acls) that only allows those users to view those groups - and thus to add those groups to mailings.

There is no built-in mailing list functionality, i.e. you send an email to a specific address, it is distributed to a group, in CiviCRM.